# What Loki option controls how often logs are written to S3 storage?

Tags: grafana-loki

I've been reading the Loki documentation to see what option controls how often the logs are written to S3 storage.

I've started with a Loki config file, as shown below.

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
  grpc_listen_port: 9095
  log_level: info

common:
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki
  storage:
    s3:
      endpoint: X.X.X.X:30008
      insecure: true
      bucketnames: my-bucket-name
      access_key_id: XXXXXXX
      secret_access_key: XXXXXXX
      s3forcepathstyle: true

schema_config:
  configs:
  - from: 2020-08-01
    store: boltdb-shipper
    object_store: s3
    schema: v11
    index:
      prefix: index_
      period: 24h
```

I see `fake/11316bdf153415ec:18d248d36be:18d2492d645:348666c5` written to S3 storage after some period of time has gone by.  For example,

```
$ mc ls --recursive myminio/my-loki-bucket
[2024-01-21 06:52:12 EST] 1.4KiB STANDARD fake/11316bdf153415ec:18d248d36be:18d2492d645:348666c5
[2024-01-21 06:52:11 EST] 2.5KiB STANDARD fake/3fa58a19fcb4b23a:18d248d36be:18d2492d646:53cf855c
[2024-01-21 06:52:11 EST] 1.5KiB STANDARD fake/439ea18af3ada610:18d248d36be:18d2492d645:3463302d
[2024-01-21 06:52:12 EST] 1.9KiB STANDARD fake/92b5be2511cd48ac:18d248d36be:18d2492d645:8eb74106
[2024-01-21 06:52:11 EST] 2.4KiB STANDARD fake/b9675d064b0a6f66:18d248d36be:18d2492d646:c73cb1da
[2024-01-21 06:52:11 EST] 2.5KiB STANDARD fake/c6d436cdc54ed457:18d248d36be:18d2492d646:b103cffd
[2024-01-21 06:52:11 EST] 1.4KiB STANDARD fake/db4bf7dd2fd629f1:18d248d36be:18d2492d645:78d6476e
[2024-01-21 10:05:19 EST]   135B STANDARD index/delete_requests/delete_requests.gz
[2024-01-21 07:08:07 EST] 1.5KiB STANDARD index/index_19742/compactor-1705838887.gz
[2024-01-20 08:39:21 EST]   198B STANDARD loki_cluster_seed.json
```

For testing purposes, I would like to know how to get these logs written to S3 storage as soon as possible.

Can someone please point me to the Loki option(s) to use?

I've tried experimenting by adding several options to the config file, as shown below:

```
compactor:
  working_directory: /tmp/compactor
  apply_retention_interval: 1m
  compaction_interval: 1m
  retention_enabled: true
  retention_delete_delay: 2h
  retention_delete_worker_count: 150
limits_config:
  retention_period: 24h
  ingestion_rate_mb: 20
  ingestion_burst_size_mb: 30
  per_stream_rate_limit: "1MB"
  per_stream_rate_limit_burst: "2MB"

ingester:
  lifecycler:
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: memberlist
      replication_factor: 1
  max_chunk_age: 30s
  chunk_idle_period: 30s
  chunk_target_size: 64000
  chunk_retain_period: 60s
  chunk_encoding: gzip
  chunk_block_size: 2048
  flush_op_timeout: 10s
  concurrent_flushes: 8
```

I append a lot of data to my `/var/log/test.log`, which is being scraped by `promtail`, with the hope of hitting some limit that will force the logs to be written to my minio `S3` storage, but after 15 minutes, `mc ls --recursive myminio/my-loki-bucket` does not show any logs written.

I was expecting `mc ls --recursive myminio/my-loki-bucket` to show new log files.

Comment: hey, did you ever figure this out? Facing the same question myself currently :)